# Users get "Authentication is required. You need to sign into your Google Acoount" error when trying to download my android app

Tags: android, google-play

My app uses AdMob. My app doesn't contain any inapp purchases. No device is excluded in developer console and devices tested had higher sdk version than minimum required. My app is optimized with proguard and then zipaligned. Users can install other apps without problems. Why are they getting this error? How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also when trying to install it via browser on a PC? In this case, where does the error occur, on the pc or the mobile device?

Which app is it?

Comment: The app is https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.subedi.filemanager. I got error on both devices. "This app is incompatible with your device" was shown on PC. Now it seems to work on both.

Answer (score 0):

I think Google Play takes random amount of time even after app being published, before it becomes available for download. Same thing happened to other person I know. After few hours of app being published (not app being uploaded) his app could be downloaded. His app could be downloaded before mine even though mine app was uploaded before his.